# ascii to hex function compiles in xcode but not theos

Tags: ios, objective-c, type-conversion, theos

I'm trying to convert ASCII to hex. Here's my function.

```
NSString *asciiToHex(NSString *input) {
    NSUInteger inputLength = [input length];
    unichar *chars = malloc(inputLength * sizeof(unichar));
    [input getCharacters:chars];
    NSMutableString *hexString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", chars[i]];
    }
    return hexString;
}
```

It works in xcode but if I try to compile it in a theos project I get this error

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'UInt8 *'
      (aka 'unsigned char *') with an rvalue of type 'void *'
    UInt8 *outBytes = malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * ((inLength / 2) + 1));
           ^
```

How can I get theos to compile it or how do I rewrite the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

malloc returns a pointer of type `void*`. Typecast rsvalue to unichar as follows

```
unichar *chars = (unichar*)malloc(inputLength * sizeof(unichar));
```